# Publish text on Facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook

i have a NSString and i want to publish it on my wall. i read the document [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/getting-started-with-the-ios-sdk/). And i follow that step. In the second step, i download sdk. There is facebook-ios-sdk.xcodeproj file  in the src folder that is in the sdk folder. i open the file and run it. but i don't know how i can import my project. furthermore there are sample projects in the folder but they aren't work.

i download FacebookSDK.framework from [here](https://developers.facebook.com). The sample projects is work in the sdk but when i import the framework and when i get instance an object in the framework, i take 15 errors. Please help me. Thank you from now.
 FBLoginView* fb = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];  // i instanced it

The error is;

```
Ld /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FaceDeneme-gatrfdmgbcwtpyecvenlafosmqfn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FaceDeneme.app/FaceDeneme normal i386
    cd /Users/apple/Documents/FaceDeneme
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
-arch i386 -isysroot /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk
-L/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FaceDeneme-gatrfdmgbcwtpyecvenlafosmqfn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
-L/Users/apple/Documents/FaceDeneme -F/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FaceDeneme-gatrfdmgbcwtpyecvenlafosmqfn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
-F/Users/apple/Documents/FaceDeneme/../FacebookSDK -filelist /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FaceDeneme-gatrfdmgbcwtpyecvenlafosmqfn/Build/Intermediates/FaceDeneme.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FaceDeneme.build/Objects-normal/i386/FaceDeneme.LinkFileList
-mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework FacebookSDK -framework Accounts -o /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FaceDeneme-gatrfdmgbcwtpyecvenlafosmqfn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FaceDeneme.app/FaceDeneme

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:   "_sqlite3_open_v2", referenced from:
      ___36-[FBCacheIndex initWithCacheFolder:]_block_invoke_0 in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)   "_sqlite3_exec", referenced from:
      ___36-[FBCacheIndex initWithCacheFolder:]_block_invoke_0 in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)   "_sqlite3_close", referenced from:
      ___23-[FBCacheIndex dealloc]_block_invoke_0 in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)   "_sqlite3_finalize", referenced from:
      _releaseStatement in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)   "_sqlite3_errmsg", referenced from:
      _releaseStatement in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      _initializeStatement in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _readEntryFromDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _fetchCurrentDiskUsage] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _removeEntryFromDatabaseForKey:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      ...   "_sqlite3_bind_text", referenced from:
      -[FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _readEntryFromDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _removeEntryFromDatabaseForKey:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)   "_sqlite3_bind_double", referenced from:
      -[FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)   "_sqlite3_bind_int", referenced from:
      -[FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _trimDatabase] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)   "_sqlite3_step", referenced from:
      -[FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _readEntryFromDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _fetchCurrentDiskUsage] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _removeEntryFromDatabaseForKey:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _dropTrimmingTable] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _trimDatabase] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      ...   "_sqlite3_prepare_v2", referenced from:
      _initializeStatement in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)   "_sqlite3_reset", referenced from:
      _initializeStatement in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)   "_sqlite3_column_text", referenced from:
      -[FBCacheIndex _readEntryFromDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _trimDatabase] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)   "_sqlite3_column_double", referenced from:
      -[FBCacheIndex _readEntryFromDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)   "_sqlite3_column_int", referenced from:
      -[FBCacheIndex _readEntryFromDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _fetchCurrentDiskUsage] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _trimDatabase] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 4):

You should follow the Facebook setup guide again. You've not set it up correctly, you're not ready to use it yet. The error you have there is telling you that you didn't include the sqlite3 library.

This library is required by the Facebook library, and it's your job to make sure it's also present in your project. This is part of the set up, check out these links:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/getting-started-with-the-ios-sdk/#project

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

Comment: there isn't any document to set it up. i opened facebook-ios-sdk.xcodeproj file on xcode and run it. there isn't any information about it on developer.facebook.

Comment: developer.facebook wrote that "Run the package to install the SDK to your preferred location, which by default is ~/Documents/FacebookSDK.

Source code for the SDK is available on GitHub." i downloaded sdk on github and run on xcode but i make a mistake. is there anyone who know this problem

Comment: when i run Facebook-ios-sdk.xcodeproj file on xcode, i just take build success message. is there anyone to do this.

Comment: i found solution to my problem. when i create new project, there are three option. i just check first option. then i import library in my project. all of this. if you need which option check please write this.